# Shortest path in Rat in a Maze with option to remove one wall

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, queue, dynamic-programming

This is the problem:
You have maps of parts of the space station, each starting at a prison exit and ending at the door to an escape pod. The map is represented as a matrix of 0s and 1s, where 0s are passable space and 1s are impassable walls. The door out of the prison is at the top left (0,0) and the door into an escape pod is at the bottom right (w-1,h-1).

Write a function answer(map) that generates the length of the shortest path from the prison door to the escape pod, where you are allowed to remove one wall as part of your remodeling plans. The path length is the total number of nodes you pass through, counting both the entrance and exit nodes. The starting and ending positions are always passable (0). The map will always be solvable, though you may or may not need to remove a wall. The height and width of the map can be from 2 to 20. Moves can only be made in cardinal directions; no diagonal moves are allowed.

To Summarize the problem: It is a simple rat in a maze problem with rat starting at (0,0) in matrix and should reach (w-1,h-1). Maze is a matrix of 0s and 1s. 0 means path and 1 means wall.You have the ability to remove one wall(change it from 0 to 1). Find the shortest path.

I've solved the problem but 3 of 5 testcases fail and I don't know what those test cases are. and I'm unable to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in Advance. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Maze{//Each cell in matrix will be this object
Maze(int i,int j){
    this.flag=false;
    this.distance=0;
    this.x=i;
    this.y=j;
}
boolean flag;
int distance;
int x;
int y;
}

class Google4_v2{
public static boolean isPresent(int x,int y,int r,int c)
{
    if((x>=0&&x<r)&&(y>=0&&y<c))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public static int solveMaze(int[][] m,int x,int y,int loop)
{
    int r=m.length;
    int c=m[0].length;
    int result=r*c;
    int min=r*c;
    Maze[][] maze=new Maze[r][c];//Array of objects
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            maze[i][j]=new Maze(i,j);
        }
    }
    Queue<Maze> q=new LinkedList<Maze>();

    Maze start=maze[x][y];
    Maze[][] spare=new Maze[r][c];
    q.add(start);//Adding source to queue
    int i=start.x,j=start.y;
    while(!q.isEmpty())
    {
        Maze temp=q.remove();
        i=temp.x;j=temp.y;
        int d=temp.distance;//distance of a cell from source 
        if(i==r-1 &&j==c-1)
        {
            result=maze[i][j].distance+1;
            break;
        }
        maze[i][j].flag=true;
        if(isPresent(i+1,j,r,c)&&maze[i+1][j].flag!=true)//check down of current cell
        {
            if(m[i+1][j]==0)//if there is path, add it to queue
            {
            maze[i+1][j].distance+=1+d;
            q.add(maze[i+1][j]);
            }
            if(m[i+1][j]==1 && maze[i+1][j].flag==false && loop==0)//if there is no path, see if breaking the wall gives a path.
            {
             int test=solveMaze(m,i+1,j,1);
             if(test>0)
             {
                test+=d+1;
                min=(test<min)?test:min;
             }
             maze[i+1][j].flag=true;
            }
        }
        if(isPresent(i,j+1,r,c)&&maze[i][j+1].flag!=true)//check right of current cell
        {
            if(m[i][j+1]==0)
            {
            maze[i][j+1].distance+=1+d;
            q.add(maze[i][j+1]);
            }
            if(m[i][j+1]==1 && maze[i][j+1].flag==false && loop==0)
            {
             int test=solveMaze(m,i,j+1,1);
             if(test>0)
             {
                test+=d+1;
                min=(test<min)?test:min;
             }
             maze[i][j+1].flag=true;
            }
        }
        if(isPresent(i-1,j,r,c)&&maze[i-1][j].flag!=true)//check up of current cell
        {
            if(m[i-1][j]==0)
            {
            maze[i-1][j].distance+=1+d;
            q.add(maze[i-1][j]);
            }
            if(m[i-1][j]==1 && maze[i-1][j].flag==false && loop==0)
            {
             int test=solveMaze(m,i-1,j,1);
             if(test>0)
             {
                test+=d+1;
                min=(test<min)?test:min;
             }
             maze[i-1][j].flag=true;
            }
        }
        if(isPresent(i,j-1,r,c)&&maze[i][j-1].flag!=true)//check left of current cell
        {
            if(m[i][j-1]==0)
            {
            maze[i][j-1].distance+=1+d;
            q.add(maze[i][j-1]);
            }
            if(m[i][j-1]==1 && maze[i][j-1].flag==false && loop==0)
            {
             int test=solveMaze(m,i,j-1,1);
             if(test>0)
             {
                test+=d+1;
                min=(test<min)?test:min;
             }
             maze[i][j-1].flag=true;
            }
        }
    }
    return ((result<min)?result:min);

}
public static int answer(int[][] m)
{
    int count;
    int r=m.length;
    int c=m[0].length;
    count=solveMaze(m,0,0,0);
    return count;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter row size ");
    int m=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter column size ");
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int[][] maze=new int[m][n];
    System.out.println("Please enter values for maze");
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            maze[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    int d=answer(maze);
    System.out.println("The maze can be solved in "+d+" steps");
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like time for you to run this with a debugger.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific. The code works with several examples. I don't know what test cases i might have missed.

Comment: Realised that this test case is failing:
0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 0

Trying to analyze why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @srk That test case fails because there is no way to get from start to finish using non-diagonal movement. And I'm pretty sure one of the numbers is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. `maze[i][j].flag=true;` needs to be put as soon as the cell is visited, inside the `if(m[i+1][j]==0)` condition. Otherwise, the distance for same cell can be added by more than one cells

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's quite hard to help you because your code is very difficult to read. The variables are generally single characters which makes it impossible to know what they are supposed to represent. Debugging it would be more help than most of us are willing to give :-)

I suggest you go about debugging your code as follows:

1. Split your `solveMaze` method into a number of smaller methods that each perform much simpler functions. For example, you have very similar code repeated 4 times for each direction. Work to get that code in a single method which can be called 4 times. Move your code to create the array into a new method. Basically each method should do one simple thing. This approach makes it much easier to find problems when they arise.
2. Write unit tests to ensure each of those methods do exactly what you expect before attempting to calculate the answer for entire mazes.
3. Once all the methods are working correctly, generate some mazes starting from very simple cases to very complex cases.
4. When a case fails, use an interactive debugger to walk through your code and see where it is going wrong.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but thats the problem. I cannot think of a test case which fails. All the cases pass for me. So, I was wondering what test cases i might have overlooked.

Comment: You need to do steps 1 and 2 before moving to step 3.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem